# How do you tap into MYOB from a .NET app?

Tags: .net, integration, myob

I'm interested in finding out how to interface a .NET app (or even just about any app running on any platform, maybe even Java or PHP) with MYOB. There's a system already in place that uses MYOB but the business owner wants their different branch offices to be able to interact with each other. I would be really interested to know the possible approaches to this problem from those of you who are familiar with this. Many thanks :)

Comment: There are rumours about MYOB Premier being moved to MS SQL Server in the near future, which will open up the data to almost anything

Comment: Those rumours still haven't amounted to anything :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an ODBC driver available [here](http://myob.com/servlet/Satellite?cid=1131944311941&pagename=MYOB%2FPage%2FPersonalisedContentPageWithNav&site=en_AU&c=Page). There maybe some limitations to it, however. Both MYOB & QuickBooks make it difficult to extract all the data -- they attempt to lock you in.

Comment: It seemed (to me) that one would have to "register" that ODBC driver in order to use it...is that correct? Also isn't it a bit risky to directly go into MYOB's database tables?

Answer (score 0):

I was at a MYOB seminar a month or so ago and MYOB are about to roll out an API for use with .net and SQLServer this year as well as a new developer/partner initiative as they are doing a major rewrite of their software.

Have to wait for the next version though...

Currently the ODBC driver is the way to do it.

Comment: did this ever happen? If so do you have a link?