# Is there a programmatic interface to MYOB data files?

Tags: myob

All I want to do is figure out what the date range of the data is. At present I have to open the file in MYOB, convert it to the v18.5 format, check it for consistency, and then run a report so that I can visually check the date range. I'd prefer something a little less labour intensive. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463874/how-do-you-tap-into-myob-from-a-net-app), as MYOB offers an ODBC driver.

UPDATE: MYOB have released an API [here](http://developer.myob.com/api/)

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be any API to AccountEdge or other software from *acclivity* (the new name for *MYOB*).

Also I don't believe that the "MYOB" file formats (emphasis on 's' - plural) are anything but proprietary and undocumented.

This leaves mainly two options...

- hack your way into the format and write a custom parser; this could be viable, but do expect bumps on the road, when the format is changed (and/or when some of the format's idiosyncrasies, not apparent during the discovery/hacking phase, eventually appear)
- automate the manual procedure you describe in the question.